# How to add red-highlighted files to git?(RubyMine)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, rubymine

I cloned some project from Github and open it in RubyMine. Then I created new branch and do branch checkout. The problem arose when I add new view files when their names(in Rubymine) become highlighted(in red).

When type git status in console I don't have these files to add them and do commit to Github(also some files are blue highlighted which I have in git status)

I found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/file-status-highlights.html) that red color means some conflict but I don't know how, when there isn't any of these files in origin master on github

Comment: I can't clearly understand, but did you add to index this new files?

Comment: no, because I don't have it at all in "modified" section in git status

Comment: Then when you type git status, you should see list of untracked files and then add them byt git add. Do you use git by CLI or some "click" feature in IDE?

Comment: I don't have it in untracked files neither, that's the problem:) I'm using git by commands

Comment: So whats the output when you type git status? You can only get conflicts when merging pushing etc.

Comment: There is some files which I also added but these views aren't there. Now I tried to add these existing files to the index and I got an error: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.

Comment: Then maybe you have more than one .git folder inside your project folder?